# Do polynomials with only negative non-leading coefficients have positive real solutions?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with only negative non-leading coefficients ($a_n = 1$ since I only care about roots, so multiplicative constants are unimportant):
$$
f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0 \quad \forall i: a_i \le 0
$$
For a problem I'm working on I must be able to guarantee that there is always at least (ideally exactly) one positive real solution.  Can I assume this?  I tried to search for it on the internet but I don't know the proper terminology, so I didn't find anything.

I only was able to proof that if all roots are real that then at least one positive root must exist, because having only negative roots would cause all coefficients to be positive, which can't be (just foil $f(x) = (x + r_1) (x + r_2) \dots$ to see why).

I played around a bit with Wolfram|Alpha and it seems to be true, but this is obviously not a prove.

Comment: Descartes sign rule guarantees that there is exactly one positive real root.

Comment: Alternatively, apply IVT to $ x^n = - ( \sum a_i x^i) $ at $ x = 0 $ and $ x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Peter does this also apply if the roots could be complex (as I said the thing in the last line only applies if all roots are real)

Comment: @CalvinLin I actually forgot to say that $a_i$ can also be zero.  Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it.

Comment: Use `\le` to get $\le$ instead of $<=$.